# Alter core block's DOM - in both output AND editor

Tags: block-editor

I'd love to alter the inbuilt block `.wp-block-file` for downloading files, so we see the file's thumbnail picture. I know I can use

```
add_filter( 'render_block', 'MyFile' , 10, 2 );

function MyFile( $block_content, $block ){
  if ( 'core/file' !== $block['blockName']) return $block_content; // check if block is file block, else return
  return "MY CUSTOM DOM using ".$block["attrs"]["href"];
}
```

but that affects only the published page and **doesn't change the block's appearance in editor**.

Is there a possibility to create e.g. a template file somewhere in my theme folder for the core block's DOM?

Comment: the appearance of the block in the editor is not rendered using PHP, it's built with JS/React, so PHP filters can never change it, there are no PHP based solutions to this

Comment: It is possible to alter block markup using JS. There are a number of filters in the handbook: https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/filters/block-filters/

Comment: This article might help: https://jschof.com/gutenberg-blocks/using-gutenberg-filters-to-extend-blocks/